# How to stop tomcat thoroughly while i have socket and thread in it

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

Currently i start some threads such scheduler and socketserver such as mina via to ServletContextListerner. But after this tomcat can not be shutdown correctly. What should i do release the socket or kill the thread .

```
public class ServerListener implements ServletContextListener{
         public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0){
          //what should i do here
         }
         public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0){
                   new Thread(new Runnable(){
                         public void run(){
                              SocketMain.main(null);

                         }
                   }).start();
                   new Thread(new Runnable(){
                         public void run(){
                              SccheduleMain.main(null);

                         }
                   }).start();
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `thread.setDaemon(true)` to tell the JVM to make the thread a daemon thread. Then it will **NOT** prevent Tomcat to shutdown.